# Template deduction reversion with function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I've had previously-working code fail on moving from g++-5 to g++-6; a previously-deducible template is no longer deducible.  A minimal example:

```
#include <math.h>

template<typename T,typename T1>
T apply(T (*func)(T1), const T1 &val)
{
  return func(val);
}

int main(void)
{
  double val1 = 0.5, val2 = apply(ceil,val1);
  return 0;
}
```

g++-6 can't seem to find the correct version of `ceil`:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:11:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘apply(<unresolved overloaded function type>, double&)’
   double val1 = 0.5, val2 = apply(ceil,val1);
                                        ^
foo.cpp:4:3: note: candidate: template<class T, class T1> T apply(T (*)(T), const T1&)
 T apply(T (*func)(T), const T1 &val)
   ^~~~~
foo.cpp:4:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
foo.cpp:11:44: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
   double val1 = 0.5, val2 = apply(ceil,val1);
```

g++-5 has no problems and works as expected.  Using the Compiler Explorer with g++ 8 at https://godbolt.org/z/oBSopG, I also see a reversion from clang-3.3 (compiles) to clang-3.4 (doesn't compile).

Given that the code still doesn't work, even in current g++, I assume that the error is on my part.  What have I done wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't use function pointers, use simple template parameters instead. Then the `apply` function could be used with just about anything that is callable. And replicates what the standard library itself is doing.

Comment: Use [`#include <cmath>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil) instead of `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: As for a simple way to solve your problem, you need to realize that the return type from the function is the same as the argument type. Which means you could drop the `T1` template argument, and use only `T` everywhere.

Comment: Actually just including `cmath` is enough (checked on godholt after editing the question).

Comment: error says `T apply(T (*func)(T),...` but in the code it is `T apply(T (*func)(T1)`, is this correct or a typo?

Comment: What is the correct version of ceil you had expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What have I done wrong and how can I fix it?

The way to fix that is to `#include <cmath>` instead of using `#include <math.h>` as mentioned in the [reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil):

```
#include <cmath> // <<< official header to use.
#include <iostream>

template<typename T,typename T1>
T apply(T (*func)(T1), const T1 &val)
{
  return func(val);
}

int main(void)
{
  double val1 = 0.5, val2 = apply(ceil,val1);

  std::cout << val1 << ' ' << val2<< std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'd be curious however to know what difference(s) from g++-5 to g++-6 triggered that.

Comment: @YSC Good question. But `cmath` always was the correct header to use with c++ IIRC.

Comment: Interestingly, using `std::ceil` will fail too. It must be `ceil`.

Comment: @CygnusX1 std::ceil does not work, as it is a function template

Comment: `ceil` is not guaranteed to be available in `<cmath>` (all standard headers put their names in the standard namespace) so this code is not portable.

Comment: @bartop I thought those are just overloads. But now I read, that there is this `double ceil(IntegralType)` that *may* be a template.

Comment: Replacing `math.h` with `cmath` does indeed fix most of my problems.  The rest may be fodder for another question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using (or planning to use) C++17, you should know that there is a more robust library function doing what you are trying to do: [std::invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)

With it, your example can be reduced to:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>

int main(void)
{
  double val1 = 0.5, val2 = std::invoke(ceil,val1);
  return 0;
}
```

Interestingly, with both your hand-crafted `apply` and the library `std::invoke`, the code will fail if you write `std::invoke(std::ceil, val1)`. This needs further investigation....